# I have a 2d list of words, how do I Assign a positive (.1 to 1) or negative (-.1 to -1) value to each of these words, and compute a sentiment score?

Tags: python, data-science

The file has one comment per line, in order from newest to oldest. You’ll need to do a little cleanup on the text, because you want to end up with:
No “\n” at the end of the line
All words in lowercase
No punctuation or numbers (i.e., keep everything that is a letter and skip the rest)

Identify some happy/positive words and some unhappy/negative words that make sense in this domain. Assign a positive (.1 to 1) or negative (-.1 to -1) value to each of these words, which you’ll use to compute a sentiment score between -1 and +1 for each comment.

Create a scatterplot of your scores. For each comment, plot its sentiment score as the y-value and its position in the list as the x-value. Use different colors for positive (> 0), negative (< 0), and neutral sentiment scores. (Note that the file has the comments in new-to-old, and your plot should go old-to-new. Try Python’s list reverse function as a possible helpful tool!)

I was able to separate it into lists but don't know how to assign the values and compute the score for each line.

Comment: Where is your code? How are we to help when we don't have access to your data and cannot reproduce your problem? We don't provide tutorials here, but provide answers to *specific* and *detailed* questions that provide a valid [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please take your time to read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If this is a home exercise, you need to demonstrate at least some effort before someone decides to help you